# Rate of convergence of $\int_0^c \sqrt{|\log(x)|} dx$ to zero as $c \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I have been looking for a way to quantify the rate of convergence for the function

$$ m(c) := \int_{0}^c \sqrt{ |\log(x)| } dx $$

in terms of $c$, as $c \to 0$. Of course, since $m(1) < \infty$, a dominated convergence argument shows that $m(c) \to 0$ as $c \to 0$, but is there also a function $g$ such that $\lim_{c \to 0} g(c) = 0$ and  $m(c) = O(g(c))$ for all $c$ small enough?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make the substitution $x = e^{-u}$ to get an integral that's probably better known.

Comment: @DanielFischer If you would like to upgrade your comment into a full answer, I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $c < 1$, the substitution $x = e^{-u}$ transforms the integral into
$$\int_{-\log c}^{\infty} \sqrt{u} e^{-u}\,du = \Gamma(3/2, -\log c)\,.$$
This is an [upper incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), and we have the known [asymptotic behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Asymptotic_behavior)
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\Gamma(s,x)}{x^{s-1}e^{-x}} = 1$$
which is easily derived via integration by parts. Repeated integration by parts yields more terms of the asymptotic expansion.

Thus for $m(c)$ we obtain
$$m(c) \sim c\sqrt{\lvert \log c\rvert}\,.$$
(We could also get that from direct integration by parts in the definition of $m(c)$ writing the integrand as $1 \cdot \sqrt{\lvert \log x\rvert}$, but writing it as a known function first has its advantages.)

Comment: Great, many thanks!